# How do i check if php server allows external curl connections

Tags: php, linux, curl, hosting

How do i check if php server allows connecting via curl to external sites before buying hosting package (or registering on free host)? I noticed that in some hosting reviews users were complaining that servers that have curl enabled often don't allow external connections...

1. I'd like to check this before purchasing/registering. Maybe there's some string in phpinfo which i can check (hosts sometimes link to their phpinfo so i don't need to be registered and create it myself) or something else i can do to check this without having account?
2. If I have to register first... maybe there are some phpinfo-like scripts with more extensive informations that i could upload and run to quickly test host?

Comment: Email the host and just ask.

Comment: ...what if they'll lie or not answer at all (especially free hosts), I'll register, upload my scripts and nothing will run?

Comment: If they are going to lie to you about something like that, they're not a good provider and you should leave them immediately. If you suspect they might lie to you, don't sign up with them.

Comment: ... if they're a free host and don't answer, register and upload a quick test script that tries to connect externally. Problem solved.

Comment: Some hosts also make a phpinfo available for potential customers.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file like this:

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?>
```

or

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(curl_version());
?>
```

That will tell you instantly.

Also, most free hosts do not offer Curl by default, due to abuse by spammers.

Answer (score 1):

You'll definitely need to buy an account before testing the server's capacities.

But some hosts allow you to test their site with a monthly contract or a XX days money back guarantee. From the top of my head, [Host gator](http://www.hostgator.com/shared.shtml) is such host.

Then when you have that account, try a small script like this (check the path to curl with your host helpdesk or documentation):

```
<?php
$var = echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/curl -L http://www.google.com");
?>
```